# Kernel of a polynomial p is invariant under a function: how is this possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $q(t) \in F[t],$ then $\operatorname{Ker}(q(f))$ is invariant under $f.$

How is this possible? If I understand the definition of invariance properly, for all elements of $$w \in \operatorname{Ker}(q(f)) \implies f(w) \in \operatorname{Ker}(q(f)).$$

However, the elements of $\operatorname{Ker}(q(f))$ are functions, no?
What is the meaning of $f(f)?$
Or am I mistaken about $\operatorname{Ker}(q(f))$ in that it is composed of the functions $f$ such that for $p$ in $F[t],$ $$p(f) = a_0 + a_1f + a_2f^2 + \cdots a_nf^n = 0?$$

Comment: is $f$ a linear function?

Comment: also, I would imagine the elements of Ker$(q(f))$ are elements in the domain of $f$, not functions

Comment: $\ker q(f)$ is the set of *vectors* killed by the linear map $q(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $q : T \to T$ and $ f : T \to T$.

The way I'm interpreting your notation: $$ \text{Ker}(q(f)) = \{ t \in T \, | \, \,  q(f(t)) = 0 \} \subseteq T$$

But in this case, the statement doesn't hold. For example, let $q(t) = t+1$, let $f(t) = 2t$. Then $q \circ f(t) = 2t + 1$. So $$\text{Ker}(q(f)) = \{ -\frac{1}{2} \}$$
but $f(-\frac{1}{2}) = -1 \notin  \text{Ker}(q(f))$; so the statement doesn't hold.

That being said, I'm not entirely clear that this is what you meant but hope that it at least goes towards making the question clearer!

Comment: Functions also form vector spaces. A zero 'vector' in such vector space is a function $\mathbb{0}(x)$ that is zero for any values of its arguments. So, a kernel of linear mapping is understood in a regular sense but by 'zero vector' a $\mathbb{0}(x)$ is understood.

Comment: I agree, but in the context that $q$ maps functions to functions, it seemed like $q(f)$ would be an element and it wouldn't be appropriate to take the kernel?

Comment: I think an abuse of notation happened somewhere here (or everywhere maybe). What was meant is that if you have a linear mapping $T\colon V \mapsto V$, then $\text{Ker}\, T = \lbrace v \in V \vert\; Tv = 0 \in V \rbrace$. So, yeah, the kernel is applied to the mapping $T$, not to some $Tv$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this makes sense (only?) in this situation: we have an $F$-vector space $V$, a linear mapping $f:V\to V$, and a polynomial $q\in F[t]$.

In that case $q(f):V\to V$ in the usual way.

Moreover,
$$
u\in\ker q(f)
\implies
q(f)u=0
\implies
f q(f)u=0
\implies
q(f)f u= 0
\implies
fu\in\ker q(f)
$$
since $f$ and $q(f)$ commute.

This shows $\ker q(f)$ is $f$-invaraint.